# Calling a Python script from a webpage

Tags: python, apache, cgi, mod-python

I've searched around for a while but I can't find a concise explanation of how to do what I want.

I have a fairly complex program which I'd like to make a simple web interface for.

Ideally there'll be a couple of text fields, "foo" and "bar" on a webpage.

When the user clicks submit, a python script "src/script.py" is run, which has access to the contents of these fields somehow.

I have apache2 and mod_python.

Comment: http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/tut-pub.html

Comment: @dm03514: No, please. `mod_python` is dead, no need to exhume it. If `mod_wsgi` is not available, even plain old CGI is better than `mod_python`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a "fairly complex program" you may want to use a small framework that takes care of grouping the parts in a "standard", i.e. supported and documented, manner. I would look into *lightweight* Python Web frameworks as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [WebApp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/). *Lightweight* in terms of both performance and learning curve.

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) you get a full overview of Python web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look into a web framework such as  [django](http://djangoproject.com) or [webOb](http://www.webob.org/)

Comment: I have, but these are way, way too complicated for what I need to do.

Comment: The problem is, that what these frameworks are abstracting away from you is waay more complex. You really don't want to deal with HTTP requests and responses yourself. With a framework like that, you can simply read the data you received, and send your response back, without having to bother with what headers you receive and send.

Comment: Well, Django might be actually _too_ complex for such a simple task. A microframework like Flask or Bottle will allow to write less boilerplate code. Nevertheless, _some_ kind of a framework is a must. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

1. user requestes a web page (a URL like http://127.0.0.1/start.html)
2. you have to serve the page to the user (either via a standalone webserver like apache or via some python lib like http.server, BaseHTTPServer, flask, cherrypy, ...)
3. user fills some values in some html form on your page (learn about [html forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)) when he hits submit another url is requested like http://127.0.0.1/myfunction.py?foo=1&bar=2
4. you have to handle the request to that url and extract the parameters from the url, for example via [cgi](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), mod_py and apache or python frameworks like flask, cherrypy, etc.. and than you would execute your code using the parameters and generate a resulting html page and serve it via those tools

If you want to keep it really simple, learn howto use flask and html forms.