# How to run Python programs on a Linux shared hosting?

Tags: python, linux, excel, shared-hosting

I wrote a Python script which does some nice stuff. It reads some inputs from an excel file and stores the results in another excel file. My plan is: I can make a web based form from which can be used to input the python program. I can make the code but how to run my program on a shared hosting platform? I am using modules like xlrd, xlwt, pysqlite, pyzipcode  etc. What are my alternatives?
My hosting: Godaddy basic shared hosting. It doesn't come with python pre-installed.

Comment: This question is way to broad for StackOverflow. But here's two pointers: You'll need to decide on a web framework for Python. I'd suggest having a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). For hosting, you may want to give  [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. For general information please see read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html)
If you want to know how, you have to more specific information. However, if you cannot/dont want to provide more information want to read some related questions.[That one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448837/how-do-i-create-a-webpage-with-buttons-that-invoke-various-python-scripts-on-the), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482151/calling-a-python-script-from-a-webpage) or in the wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts)

But, before doing getting to work, you have to install python on your webhosting.
You can read more about that [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/815/why-isnt-my-python-script-working?locale=de-DE&countrysite=de) and [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7254/can-i-use-python-2-7-2-with-my-hosting-account?locale=de-DE&countrysite=de). However, if you use modules which do not come naturally with python, you have to install them as well.

Comment: Hi @Stophface, I checked. My web hosting account doesn't support Python. A more specific question is: provided that I am using variety of modules in my  python code and my hosting account doesn't support Python, how can I use my code for webpage based applications?

Comment: @Karvy1 Then you might want to change your webhosting account, upgrade it or use this one https://www.pythonanywhere.com/